# How to figure out the average CPI of two processor?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Consider two processors – Processor A and Processor B. 
Processor A is a single-cycle MIPS processor with a clock period of 2000 ps and Processor B
is a pipelined MIPS processor with a clock period of 500 ps. Processor B has
a 5-stage pipeline.

For a workload that causes pipeline stalls in 20% of execution slots, what are the
average CPI and IPC values for the two processors?

I am trying to find the CPI of both of these processors. I know you can divide the number of cycles by the number of instructions to get the CPI but I don't know the number of instructions so I cannot use that here. I know that if you have the distribution of the cycles and the percentage they complete in you can use that to calculate the CPI but I have absolutely no idea how to find the CPI here.

Comment: Can you provide an attempt at a solution, then maybe someone will tell you where you may have gone wrong. At the moment, it looks like you are attempting to pass off your homework.

Comment: I honestly can't because I quite literally don't know how to attempt it. I'd usually find the CPI using one of the two methods stated above but as far as I can see neither of them will work for it. I don't know and can't find a third method to attempt it. Which is the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

CPI is an average rate so you could just make up any number of instructions you want (like 100), do the math to find cycles using the other info you're given, then divide.

It should then become obvious how you could have done the algebra without using any specific numbers.  The number of instructions cancels out.